# How to modify file content using python?

Tags: python, file, abstract-syntax-tree

The following code reads a file, uses syntax tree to append fullstop to docstrings of that file. How can I save changes made in called file? I understand present code doesn't change content in original file but the local variables accessing it. Can you suggest changes, if possible provide learning resource as well?

**astcode.py**

```
import ast
import sys
import os

filename = sys.argv[1]


# """Getting all the functions"""
ast_filename = os.path.splitext(ast.__file__)[0] + '.py'

with open(filename) as fd:
    file_contents = fd.read()

module = ast.parse(file_contents)

# with open(filename, 'w') as file:
# module level
if(isinstance(module.body[0], ast.Expr)):
    docstr = module.body[0].value.s
    if(module.body[0].value.s not in '.'):
        docstr += '.'
        # ast.dump(module, include_attributes=True)
    print(docstr)


# function level
function_definitions = [node for node in module.body if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]

for function in function_definitions:
    # next_node = function_definitions[idx].body
    next_node = function.body
    for new_node in next_node:
        if(isinstance(new_node, ast.Expr)):
            if(isinstance(new_node.value, ast.Str)):
                # Docstring stored in docstr variable.
                docstr = new_node.value.s

                if(docstr[-1] not in '.'):
                    new_node.value.s += '.'
                
                # astString = ast.dump(new_node, annotate_fields=True, include_attributes=True)
                # print(astString)
                # compile(astString, filename, 'eval')
                # print(exec(astString))
                print(new_node.value.s)

    # for line in module:
        # file.write(line)
```

## Example

**testfile.py**

```
def readDictionaryFile(dictionary_filename):
    """readDictionaryfile doc string"""
    return []

def readTextFile(text_filename):
    """readTextfile doc string"""
    return []
```

> **$** python3 astcode.py testfile.py

### Expected

**testfile.py**

```
def readDictionaryFile(dictionary_filename):
    """readDictionaryfile doc string."""
    return []

def readTextFile(text_filename):
    """readTextfile doc string."""
    return []
```

Note: Fullstop(.) appended.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AST library, but I believe the way to write it back to a file is with the dump(...) method, which can convert the entire AST into a single string.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: @user1324109 Have you looked at any examples there?

Comment: @user1324109 dump function returns formatted dump of the tree in node and helps in debugging, the string you are referring shows the edited content with row/column numbers if passed with optional arguments. I believe there's something to do with compile function of ast library itself, I am leaving a link to it... [AST Compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile). I hope you would like it. My question is not solved yet... do share your thoughts if you find something. Thanks

Comment: I ran this on a sample python file and got an attribute error on value.s Perhaps a small input and expected output would make it more clear. Is the question about the actual output, or just how to write to a file?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I have updated code. Now it should work fine.

Comment: I'm noticing that 3.9 has https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.unparse but I'm on 3.8 right now. I can't follow up right now, but will check later.

Comment: Thanks @KennyOstrom.

Comment: @Manuel I stand corrected.  I didn't look closely enough before I posted.  Thanks, this is an interesting topic.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation link, I notice there's a NodeVisitor and NodeTransformer with a code example. I looked at how they unparse a function def, and it's basically the same as you've done in your original question, so I used that.

```
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer
class MyDocstringTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        if len(node.body):
            if isinstance(node.body[0], ast.Expr):
                if isinstance(node.body[0].value, ast.Constant):
                    if isinstance(node.body[0].value.value, str):
                        docstring = node.body[0].value.value
                        node.body[0].value.value = docstring + '.'
        return node
```

Using python 3.9's ast module gets us https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.unparse which is about as close as we can get to changing the ast node and then rewriting the original file.

```
tree = ast.parse(file_contents)
new_tree = MyDocstringTransformer().visit(tree)
print(ast.unparse(new_tree))
```

Instead of just overwriting to the same filename, you may want to write to a temp file, then let the OS attempt to delete the old file and rename the temp file to the old name, thus performing the replace in the OS.

Comment: Thanks @KennyOstrom. Why shouldn't I overwrite to the same file?